# ReactJS and Redux: Need to refresh the page everytime to get the updated content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have developed an app in ReactJS and using Redux for state management.

Problem: Whenever I navigate to different page (suppose from product page to cart page on clicking add to cart), the changes doesn't occur in first render. I have to refresh the page to see the added product. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you restarted the project? Close your code editor and then open the project again. If its not working, then your content isn't updating on the page because u didnt use any UseEffects?

Answer (score 0):

In cart component you should have something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  --fetch data...
  }, [the item that if changes, the component should be rerender]);
```